# Did ancient Egyptian gods have weapons like the Greek gods?

Tags: egyptian, weapons

Did ancient Egyptian gods have weapons, like the Greek gods (Zeus's thunderbolt or Poseidon's trident, for example)? If so, who made them? I've never read anywhere where they had weapons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only particular weapon given more than passing mention that I can find is Isis's harpoon in [The Contendings of Horus and Seth](http://www.touregypt.net/contendingshorusseth.htm) (part of the Papyrus Chester Beatty I), which she makes herself from some yarn and copper:

> Then she fetched a skein of yarn. She fashioned a line, fetched a deben-weight's (worth) of copper, cast it in (the form of) a harpoon, tied the line to it, and hurled it into the water at the spot where Horus and Seth had submerged. / But then the copper (barb) bit into the person of her son Horus. So Horus let out a loud shriek, saying: Help me, mother Isis, my mother. Appeal to your copper (barb) to let go of me. I am Horus, son of Isis. thereupon Isis let out a loud shriek and told  copper (barb): Let go of him. See, it is my son Horus. He is my child. So her copper (barb) let go of him.

The same story contains other references to weapons used by the gods, but they don't seem to have any special properties, or supernatural qualities.

- > ...having his cleaver of 16 deben-weight in his hand.

  (16 deben-weight would be about 1.5 kg, I believe, which [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_axe) is a pretty typical weight for an axe designed for warfare)
- > ...seized the copper (knife), cut off his hand(s)
- > Horus took his copper (harpoon) and hurled it at the person of Seth.

Answer (score 4):

It was fairly typical for Indo-European gods to have associated weapons or tools. For example, Thor's hammer and [Lugh's spear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lugh#Lugh.27s_Spear). Vishnu, having 4 arms, can dual-wield a club and a [oddjob-esque death Frisbee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarshana_Chakra).

However, Semitic people did their deities a bit differently. They tended to have non-human aspects, in some cases being entirely based on animals. Egypt particularly tended towards the latter. There are humanoid depictions of their main gods holding flails, but those are generally considered agricultural (herding) symbols rather than war weapons.

Answer (score -2):

The Gods of Egypt use weapons that they fashion themselves. The had spears and swords they use against Apep. They use wands or was and amulets, fill them with magic or inscribe them with words of power for specific purposes. There greatest weapon was the magic of words and transformation/shapeshifting of objects or themselves.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mythology Stack Exchange. Can you provide weapons to back up the claims you make here, and perhaps elaborate a little on the specific weapons you list?